# Indicating format of multiple numbers in numpy.savetxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, format, save

I want to save an array using `numpy.savetxt`. The array contains eight numbers. Only the format of the first number is different with respect to the latter seven. I know I can set the format of numbers as follows:

```
numpy.savetxt(filename, array, fmt = "%03d" "%.10f" "%.10f" "%.10f" "%.10f" "%.10f" "%.10f" "%.10f")
```

Here `filename` is just the name of my file e.g. `numbers.dat` and `array` is a 1D numpy array containing my eight numbers.

The above line of code works but looks ridiculous because I'm specifying each individual format of my numbers. How can I indicate that the latter seven numbers have the same format in a pythonic way?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just simplify it:

```
"%03d" + "%.10f"*7
```

Comment: Well that turned out to be easy. Appreciate the help!