# numpy.savetxt - Save a np.array with different types

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, format, save

This question is connected to others already existing (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117490/indicating-format-of-multiple-numbers-in-numpy-savetxt)), but I could not solve by following the solutions provided in there. So I try to ask again.

I have 7 parameters, say `a1`, `a2`, `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4` and `b5`.
The 'a' parameters are integers, while the 'b' parameters are floats.
As an example, take

```
a1=1, a2=500, b1=1.0, b2=1.0, b3=-0.866025, b4=0.0, b5=-0.1.
```

I would like to save these parameters into a file. The code for doing this reads:

```
f = open("params.txt",'w')
arr=np.array((a1,a2,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5))
arrform=' '.join(['%d']*2 + ['%f']*5)
np.savetxt(f,arr,fmt=arrform)
f.close()
```

When executing this code I get the following error message:

`fmt has wrong number of % formats:  %d %d %f %f %f %f %f`

Could you, please, tell me what is my mistake?

Comment: `print(arrform%(a1,a2,...), file=f)` of `f.write(...)` should be enough if those variables are scalars.  You don't need `numpy` to format and write a tuple of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

use column_stack instead array

```
f = open("params.txt",'w')
arr=np.column_stack((a1,a2,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5))
arrform=' '.join(['%d']*2 + ['%f']*5)
np.savetxt(f,arr,fmt=arrform)
f.close()
```